# How to bypass Buffer object error in client side js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browser, client-side

I'm trying to verify a 2FA code using `speakeasy` library :

```
try {
        var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
          secret: keyBase32_,
          encoding: 'base32',
          token: code as string,
        });
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
error:  ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
  at Object.digest (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (lockdown.umd.min.js:1:22409)), <anonymous>:52045:13)
  at Object.hotpGenerate (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (lockdown.umd.min.js:1:22409)), <anonymous>:52061:52)
  at Function.hotpVerifyDelta [as verifyDelta] (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (lockdown.umd.min.js:1:22409)), <anonymous>:52084:36)
  at Function.totpVerifyDelta [as verifyDelta] (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (lockdown.umd.min.js:1:22409)), <anonymous>:52113:38)
  at Function.totpVerify [as verify] (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (lockdown.umd.min.js:1:22409)), <anonymous>:52120:33)
  at onRpcRequest (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (lockdown.umd.min.js:1:22409)), <anonymous>:54322:41)
  at async f.executeInSnapContext (bundle.js:2:772169)
  at async bundle.js:2:767893
  at async Object.snapRpc (bundle.js:2:773159)
  at async f.onCommandRequest (bundle.js:2:769013)
```

I am running this inside a Chrome extension. When I ran the code locally it worked fine but fails in the browser. I read that it's because the Buffer global object is not available in browsers so how can I bypass this?

Any help will be appreciated.